# Send emails without blocking ui

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I have a file sharing platform using codeigniter as framework,
When a user creates a folder or uploads a new document it should send a email notification to all the managers, and when an manager uploads a file it should send a notification to the user.

I already coded all the process but when someone created a new folder it's redirected inside the new folder (the redirection is made via javascript and i send the new folder ID via json in the controller).

I've tried adding the email part in the model after the folder creation but before the ID return to controller, and at the end of the controller function but it has a delay while it sends the email (about 8 seconds)

Is there any method to send async/background without delaying the UI?

Comment: Use a queue. There appear to be a variety of options in CI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@javier: I generally insert all the emails to be sent to a table called **email_queue**,

Another *php process* continuously iterates the **email_queue** table for any emails to be sent.

I hope you got what I wanted to say. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Do you have an example of the cronjob on a windows server to iterate on the process??

Comment: Sorry I use ubuntu linux server,

cronjob can be like this: 

*/30 * * * *   php /var/www/.../email_queue_runner.php
- this runs every 30 mins.

email_queue table
id, date, subject, body, dest_email, from_email, email_is_sent (0,1)

php code can be: 
- email_queue_runner.php

if(email_is_sent==0){
 send_email($from_email,$subject,$body, $dest_email);
}

Hope you will understand my pseudo code.

Comment: in windows server you can't run cronjob, try and use vagrant or docker.

Comment: I got it working with a batch file and windows task scheduler opening and closing chrome every 2 mins!!